# C++. В массив не добавляются символы кириллицы. (Впрочем, мб и добавляются, но как-то криво)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

В общем, проблема заключается в том, что, при вводе строки латиницей, код отрабатывает совершенно нормально. Если же ввести кириллицу, то массив, не знаю, не сохраняет символы (либо сохраняет как-то непонятно). При использовании закомментированных строк либо ничего не меняется, либо становится только хуже (пример внизу).

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>

int main() {
    // SetConsoleCP(1251);
    // SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    // setlocale(0, "Russian");

    char main_string[256], result_string[128];
    int a, b, counter = 0;
    std::cout << "enter the string\n";
    std::cin.getline(main_string, 256);
    std::cout << "you entered: \n" << main_string << std::endl;
    std::cout << "enter the number A\n";
    std::cin >> a;
    std::cout << "enter the number B\n";
    std::cin >> b;

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(main_string); i++) {
        if (i > a - 1 and i < b - 1) {
            result_string[counter++] = main_string[i];
        }
    }

    std::cout << "result: ";

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(result_string); i++) {
        std::cout << result_string[i];
    }

}
```

Вот результат при использовании латиницы:

```
enter the string
testing string
you entered: 
testing string
enter the number A
1
enter the number B
5
result: est
```

А вот результат при вводе кириллицы:

```
enter the string
тестовая строка
you entered: 

enter the number A
1
enter the number B
5
result:
```

При использовании `SetConsoleCP(1251);` ничего не меняется

```
введите строку
тестовая строка
вы ввели: 

введите номер A
1
введите номер B
5
result:
```

При использовании `SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);` происходит это:

```
РІРІРµРґРёС‚Рµ СЃС‚СЂРѕРєСѓ
тестовая строка
РІС‹ РІРІРµР»Рё: 

РІРІРµРґРёС‚Рµ РЅРѕРјРµСЂ A
1
РІРІРµРґРёС‚Рµ РЅРѕРјРµСЂ B
5
```

при использовании всех 3 строк, а именно:

```
SetConsoleCP(1251);
SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
setlocale(0, "Russian");
```

происходит это:

```
РІРІРµРґРёС‚Рµ СЃС‚СЂРѕРєСѓ
тестовая строка
РІС‹ РІРІРµР»Рё: 
тестовая строка
РІРІРµРґРёС‚Рµ РЅРѕРјРµСЂ A
1
РІРІРµРґРёС‚Рµ РЅРѕРјРµСЂ B
5
result: естяяяяяА†с
```

Comment: Как оно с and собралось?)

Comment: У меня в vsc все из коробки работает